# Start vm failed after update virtualbox from 5.0.24 to 5.1

Tags: virtualbox

vboxmanage startvm shows the following message:

> VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'VM02' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1) 
> VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

/var/log/syslog shows there's a version mismatch, but i don't know where is it:

> kernel: [45470.001207] SUP_IOCTL_COOKIE: Version mismatch. Requested: 0x260000  Min: 0x260000  Current: 0x240000

headless -h shows this:

> VBoxHeadless: Error -1912 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
>
> VBoxHeadless: RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912

vm works fine after removing virtualbox 5.1 and reinstalled 5.0.24

Here's how I upgrade to 5.1.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove virtualbox-5.0
sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1
sudo vboxmanage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.0-108711.vbox-extpack --replace
```

Is there something wrong when I upgrade virtualbox?

What can I do to get it work on 5.1? OS is ubuntu 16.04 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright, finally i made it, tried to edit michael's answer but rejected.
posting here:

## ubuntu solution:

version mismatch is caused by the old modules, to clean it up:

```bash
# stop all vbox services
sudo service vboxblahblah stop
# check all vbox is not running
ps -e | grep -i vbox
# remove 5.0 or maybe 5.1
sudo apt remove virtualbox-5.0
cd /
# find all vbox files to delete
sudo find -iname "vbox" 2>/dev/null
```

remove all vbox binaries and sources, then restart to install virtualbox-5.1

Answer (score 37):

Had the same problem on Debian where I accidentally installed the Debian `virtualbox-dkms` package along with the Oracle version of `virtualbox-5.1` which naturally were different versions.

Check via `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`, if you have something like the following, you have the same situation.

```
ii  virtualbox-5.1  5.1.8-111374~Debian~jessie amd64 Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkms 5.1.6-dfsg-2 all           x86   virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
```

```

Fixed it by:

1. `sudo rmmod vboxpci vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxdrv`
2. `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms`
3. `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`.

Comment: I had a similar issue after upgrading from VirtualBox 5.1 to 5.2. The solution proposed here worked for me as well.

Comment: This happened in my Ubuntu 16.04: `virtualbox = 5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2`, `virtualbox-dkms = 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2`. For some reason, the dkms package was pinned to 5.0. A manual `apt-get install vitualbox-dkms` fixed it.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and ended up with the mish-mash of versions as you described, didn't even think to check version mismatches. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, after a while I figured out there is a problem in removing the old modules. After uninstalling, rebooting and reinstalling I ran:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/modules/4.5.7-202.fc23.x86_64/extra/vbox*
sudo rmmod vboxpci
sudo rmmod vboxnetadp
sudo rmmod vboxnetflt
sudo rmmod vboxdrv
sudo vboxconfig
```

Then it worked.

Hope this helps

Comment: i can't get it, why rmmod after install? uninstall 5.1 reboot and install 5.1 then follow your approach didnot work, i'm now trying to revert to 5.0. oh, there's no this folder btw: /usr/lib/modules/4.5.7-202.fc23.x86_64/

Comment: Because the uninstall reboot reinstall didn't work. I thought there might be a problem in removing the old modules, so just in case, I got rid of them.

Comment: That folder is where kernel modules are on my machine (Fedora 23), they will be somewhere else on yours.

Comment: find something resemble what you said `/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox` i kept the 4.4.0-31 folder and removed all older than 4.4.0-31, still not working

Comment: after removing everything i found related to vbox, i made it, tried to edit your answer but rejected, posting another, appreciate the help

Comment: IMO this is the correct answer (the path to the modules can vary). It's important to rmmod the modules before calling vboxconfig, otherwise vboxconfig will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Tried all the answers above, none worked. Issue was the debian virtualbox was uninstalled properly. The following worked:

1. Close virtualbox
2. sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.1
3. sudo apt-get install virtualbox
4. sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-qt virtualbox-dkms
5. sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
6. sudo vboxconfig

Comment: do you lose your VMs doing this?

Comment: No your VM's are saved in your user directory and left untouched. Never hurts to do a backup though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

How I did fix on Ubuntu 14.04 server x64:

I try to do everything above, nothing help.

1. stop first all vbox services (vboxautostart, vboxbaloon vboxdrv and vboxweb)
2. wait for 10-15 seconds and check is there any vbox
3. `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.*`
4. Try first with command : `sudo update-grub`
5. reboot machine and than try install `virtualbox-5.*`
6. If doesn't work than stop all vbox services, remove `virtualbox-5.*`
7. `sudo apt-get autoremove` (all kernel modules to last one, I had 3 versions and I do it twice apt-get autoremove)
8. `sudo update-grub`
9. `reboot`
10. install `virtualbox-5.1` and after that it is working